# How to get jQuery to open a page in the current tab rather than a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before saying  that the answers are already on the forum take note that I have already tried them to no avail. Basically the problem is that when I press enter to search it opens the google page in a new tab. How do I get it to open in the current tab?

This is the HTML

```
<div class="Search">
    <img id="pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/fjAZgqe.png" alt="moose"/>
    <form class="websearch">
        <input autofocus placeholder="Google" type="text" id="GGLSite"> <!--this   creates the textbox they can use to search. Note the ID is what   the function grabs -->  
        <input type="button" id="GGLmeme" onclick="DoGGL()" style="display: none;" value="Search GGL"> <!-- this is just the button that calls the   function. The value is whats shown on the button --> 
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript

```
function DoGGL(){  
    var GGLVar = document.getElementById("GGLSite").value; //this grabs the variable (search terms) from the textbox  
    var NewURL = "https://www.google.se/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=" + GGLVar; //this puts the site they typed into the wayback machines URL  

    var NewTabGGL = window.open(NewURL, "_blank"); //this opens a new tab with the URL.   
    if (NewTabGGL){ //make sure the browser can allow it   
        NewTabGGL.focus(); //switches them to the new tab -- done!  
    }  
    else{  
        alert("Popup didnt work");  
    }  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#GGLSite').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
        $('#GGLmeme').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: use the target = "_self" instead of "_blank". i.e, window.open(NewURL, "_self")

Comment: Did you try using window.location.href = "desiredUrl"?

Comment: @DinoMyte I tried that, it still didn't work.

Comment: If you don't want to open in a new tab so why do you have this line:
`var NewTabGGL = window.open(NewURL, "_blank"); //this opens a new tab with the URL.`
Your comment there saying that it will open it in new tab ?!

Comment: @wilsotobianco I tried that earlier, that didn't work aswell.

Comment: Understood. Can you provide a jsFiddle or something like that so we can help?

Comment: Here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/p8wp0m8u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tweaks on your code (read the comments):

**Javascript**

```
// Remember capitalized functions are supposed to be used with the new operator, hence, this function must not be capitalized
function doGGL(event){

    // Here we prevent the default behavior of the form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // Javascript variables must not be capitalized
    var gGLVar = document.getElementById("GGLSite").value;
    var newURL = "https://www.google.se/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=" + gGLVar;

    // This sentence navigates to desired URL in the same window
    window.location.href = newURL;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // There's no need to catch the enter key because that's the form default behavior. So I'm attaching the submit event to the function defined above
  $('.websearch').on('submit', doGGL);
});
```

This didn't work in jsFiddle so I tried it in a local file called index.html with the same HTML, CSS but replacing the javascript with the latter.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just get to the page from this page, window.location = NewURL; would work. I don't see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: That didn't work. It doesn't bring me to the google link. What I am trying to do is: I have a custom splash page for my browser. I have various links that I commonly visit. I also have a search bar that put whatever I put in it in a google search for me. I just want the results to open in the same tab that I write them in. Not open a new tab.

Comment: Why don't you add a `<div id="google-response">` and an ajax request to the google API. then load the html into your div